# Posix threads and priority

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I want to set pthread priority using pthread_attr_setschedparam(). I have tried to resolve this issue but couldn't do it. I also consulted internet which also uses the same functions. Pthread_create always fail. Can someone help me?

Sorry for my english, i'm spanish...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sched.h>

struct Data{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int cnt;
};

//VARIABLES GLOBALES


void *A(void *a) {
    struct Data* dato = a;
    int prio = 3;
    sleep(3);
    printf("Proceso A [:%d]  Inicio\n", prio); 
    pthread_mutex_lock( &dato->mutex );
    ++dato->cnt;
    printf("Proceso A. Contador ++\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &dato->mutex );
    printf("Proceso A [%d] Fin\n", prio);
    return NULL;
}  

void *M(void *a) {
    struct Data* dato = a;
    int prio = 2;
    printf("Proceso M [%d] Inicio\n", prio); 
    sleep(5);
    //ESPERA ACTIVA
    printf("Proceso M. Espera activa: 15 s\n");
    time_t fin = time(0) + 15;
    while (time(0) < fin){
        /* esperar activamente */ 
    }
    //FIN ESPERA ACTIVA

    printf("Proceso M [%d] Fin\n", prio);
    return NULL;
}

void *B(void *a) {
    struct Data* dato = a;
    int prio = 1;
    sleep(1);
    printf("Proceso B [%d] Inicio\n", prio); 
    pthread_mutex_lock( &dato->mutex);
    //ESPERA ACTIVA
    printf("Proceso B. Espera activa: 7 s\n");
    time_t fin = time(0) + 7;
    while (time(0) < fin){
        /* esperar activamente */ 
    }
    //FIN ESPERA ACTIVA

    ++dato->cnt;
    printf("Proceso B. Contador ++\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &dato->mutex);
    printf("Proceso B [%d] Fin\n", prio);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    //crear Mutex
    printf("Mutex sin atributos especiales\n"); 
    struct Data dato = {PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, 0};

    //POLITICA
    int prio = 10;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    struct sched_param param;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);    //politica explicita
    if(pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO)){             //FIFO
        printf("Fallo al establecer la politica");  
    }
    if (pthread_attr_getschedparam(&attr, &param))
        printf ("No puedo obtener los parámetros");
    else{
        param.sched_priority = prio;                                    //prioridad
        if (pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param))
        printf("No puedo cambiar la prioridad");
    }
    //PRIORIDAD MAIN
    /*pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &param);*/

    //CREACION HEBRAS
    pthread_t threads[3];
    //crear hebra A
    /*param.sched_priority = 3;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);*/
    if (pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, A, &dato)) printf("Fallo al crear la hebra A\n");
    //crear hebra M
    param.sched_priority = 2;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);
    if (pthread_create(&threads[1], &attr, M, &dato)) printf("Fallo al crear la hebra M\n");
    //crear hebra B
    param.sched_priority = 1;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &param);
    if (pthread_create(&threads[2], &attr, B, &dato)) printf("Fallo al crear la hebra B\n");


    //Destruir atributo (liberar recurso)
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    printf("Esperando finalizar\n");
    //esperar hebra 1
    pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
    //esperar hebra 2
    pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);
    //esperar hebra 3
    pthread_join(threads[2],NULL);
    //destruir mutex
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&dato.mutex);
    //FIN
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error code does pthread_create() return? If you can, do something like `int result = pthread_create(...); if (result) printf("pthread_create() failed: %s\n", strerror(result));` to display a text representation of the error (instead of just the error number, which we would then have to look up...)

Comment: The error code is "Operation not permitted" :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (3) pthread_create

> EPERM  No permission to set the scheduling policy and parameters specified in attr.

My guess is you are failing on the `pthread_create` because of the setschedule calls before it.  Try running as root if you want to change schedules.  (And check your return codes!)

Comment: Thanks!! sudo was the solution!! :D

Comment: You're correct that he needs to run as root, but not because of any setschedule calls. He's trying to change the priority to 10. The default priority for users on linux is 20, and anyone can give themselves worse priority than that (lower is better; bigger is worse). So changing it to 21 or 30 would work, I'm guessing (but would _decrease_ the priority of the task). If you want to improve your priority (lower number) compared to the user default of 20, you need elevated permissions (i.e., root/sudo).

Comment: @Dave Lillethun, it's not just a matter of priorities.  You need proper permissions to change the scheduling policy.  See [sched_setscheduler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/sched_setscheduler.html)

Comment: @Duck I was getting confused between static priority and dynamic priority. What I was talking about was the dynamic priority (AKA, "nice" value), but what the OP is doing is static priority. So I was off on that one... but I'll leave the comment for future readers; just note that my comment above is referring to "nice" values and not what the OP is doing.